# Filtering Array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am attempting to filter an array of JSON objects. I am new to JavaScript and trying to do it in coding languages that I used to. Basically, I want to take the following array of objects.

```
     var result = [
                                {
                                    date : '2016-11-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },

                                {
                                    date : '2016-10-21',
                                    name: 'Bill',
                                    score: 0.2081911},

                                {
                                    date : '2016-10-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                },
                                {
                                    date : '2016-10-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },

                                {
                                    date : '2016-11-21',
                                    name: 'Bill',
                                    score: 0.2081911},

                                {
                                    date : '2016-11-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                },
                                {
                                    date : '2016-12-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },

                                {
                                    date : '2016-12-21',
                                    name: 'Bill',
                                    score: 0.2081911},

                                {
                                    date : '2016-12-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                }




  ]
```

I then want to filter based on objects. So for example.

```
var selected_Names = ['Bob','Mary']
```

I want to return Bob and Mary's information only in this scenario.

```
 [
                                {
                                    date : '2016-11-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },



                                {
                                    date : '2016-10-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                },
                                {
                                    date : '2016-10-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },



                                {
                                    date : '2016-11-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                },
                                {
                                    date : '2016-12-21',
                                    name: 'Bob',
                                    score: 0.1034947
                                },



                                {
                                    date : '2016-12-21',
                                    name: 'Mary',
                                    score: 0.234947
                                }




  ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const result = [{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947},{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947},{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947},{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947}];
  
const filterNames = arr => names => arr.filter(e => names.includes(e.name));

const names = ['Bob', 'Mary'];

const res = filterNames(result)(names);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much!